# Sort dictionary by key alphabetically

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, python-3.5

I'm having trouble sorting my `dictionary` alphabetically by its `keys`.

Here's my code:

```
colorSizes = {'Rust': ['SIZE 8', 'SIZE 10', 'SIZE 12', 'SIZE 14', 'SIZE 16', 'SIZE 18'], 
              'Middle Blue': ['SIZE 8', 'SIZE 10', 'SIZE 12', 'SIZE 14', 'SIZE 16', 'SIZE 18'], 
              'Grey': ['SIZE 8', 'SIZE 10', 'SIZE 12', 'SIZE 14', 'SIZE 16', 'SIZE 18'], 
              'Aqua': ['SIZE 8', 'SIZE 10', 'SIZE 12', 'SIZE 14', 'SIZE 16', 'SIZE 18'], 
              'Navy': ['SIZE 8', 'SIZE 10', 'SIZE 12', 'SIZE 14', 'SIZE 16']}

realColor = {}
for key in sorted(colorSizes.keys()):
    realColor[key] = colorSizes.get(key)

print(realColor)
```

What I get:

> {'Yellow/Fuschia':['Large', 'Extra Large'], 
>                 'Black':['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']}

What I wanna get:

> {'Black':['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], 'Yellow/Fuschia':['Large', 'Extra Large']}

Thanks!

Comment: You can't sort a dict, because dicts don't have an order. Take a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Python `dict`'s are unordered by default. You should either create a list of tuples from it and sort it, or consider [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries in python versions < 3.6 are unordered, sorting and reinserting is meaningless.

---

As a fix, either

1. Switch to python3.6 (keep in mind the [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756429/sort-dict-by-key-alphabetically/45756466?noredirect=1#comment78470265_45756466)), or
2. Use an `OrderedDict`

For the second option, replace `realColor = {}` with a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
realColor = OrderedDict()
```

---

Here's an example of how an `OrderedDict` remembers the order of insertion:

```
dict1 = {}
dict1['k'] = 1
dict1['aSDFDF'] = 1234

print(dict1) # {'aSDFDF': 1234, 'k': 1}

from collections import OrderedDict
dict2 = OrderedDict()
dict2['k'] = 1
dict2['aSDFDF'] = 1234

print(dict2) # OrderedDict([('k', 1), ('aSDFDF', 1234)])
```

The `__repr__` might be different, but the latter is still a dictionary and can be used accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot! any idea on how to remove the 'OrderedDict(.....)' ?

Comment: @JohnDoes Like I said, the `__repr__` (as in, how it is printed out) is different, but it is used _exactly_ the same as a normal dictionary.

Comment: `dict`s being ordered in Python 3.6 are an implementation detail, not an official language feature. So probably not a good idea to rely on it. [(source)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation)